# MUI Styled components lost styling after updating node modules

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

we are using @mui as our frontend framework. Everything was great for long time until recently. After deleting and reinstalling node_modules, components lost styling.

After debugging noticed compiler error in markup. Instead of component list now it's
`[object Object]`.

[image]

Does anyone have any guess?

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on what version of MaterialUI you have now. The `sx` prop only works with MaterialUI version 5. https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/

Comment: It was working fine, got broken after npm install, I doubt modules got downgraded by npm install :(.